# How to pass a C string to a Ruby method using mruby?

Tags: c, mruby

I am getting started with C and mruby. I have a program that calls to a Ruby function using the mruby `mrb_load_string` function. I want to pass the argument from the C function to the Ruby function. How can I achieve this?

```
void on_key(const char *key) {
  mrb_load_string(mrb, "input_received()"); // how do I pass key as an argument?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ruby function takes a string as a parameter input, then:

```
void on_key(const char *key) {
  char arg[64];
  sprintf(arg,"input_received(\"%s\")",key);//Embed key as an argument to the function
  mrb_load_string(mrb, arg); 
}
```

should do what you wanted.